# Check if a user has a role in a completely different server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Say if someone used a command in a random server with the same bot, it would detect if that user has a specific role in a different server they are in.

Could anyone tell me how/if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`commands.check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands.check#discord.ext.commands.check) and verify if the wanted role is in [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member.roles#discord.Member.roles) using the member object for the other guild.

This function will get a guild and a role in that guild then check if it's in the member roles

```py
async def another_guild_role(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(12345)    # change id here for wanted guild
    role = guild.get_role(12345)    # change id here for wanted role

    member = guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)
    # if member is not in bot chache make an API request
    if not member:
        member = guild.fetch_member(ctx.author.id)

    return role in member.roles
```

This is how you would include it in your command.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.check(another_guild_role)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Yes you have the role")
```